# I need to change the color of a text shown by setEmptyText in ListFragment with Android Studio

Tags: android, fragment

In this Android class of **ListFragment** the text that is displayed by **setEmptyText** is default is white, I need to change this color, as I do

```
public class DevicesFragment extends ListFragment {
.
.


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(discoveryBroadcastReceiver, discoveryIntentFilter);
    if(bluetoothAdapter == null) {
       // the color of this text I need to customize!!
        setEmptyText("<Bluetooth LE no soportado>");
    } else if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // the color of this text I need to customize!!
        setEmptyText("<Bluetooth esta deshabilitado!>");
        if (menu != null) {
            listItems.clear();
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            menu.findItem(R.id.ble_scan).setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {

    // the color of this text I need to customize!!
        setEmptyText("Use SCAN para actualizar dispositivos Bluetooth LE disponibles");
        if (menu != null)
            menu.findItem(R.id.ble_scan).setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the empty `TextView` as:

```
TextView emptyTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
```

or you can call `getListView().getEmptyView()`. It will return either the `TextView` with id `android.R.id.empty` (if supplied in the layout), or the standard `TextView` that is used otherwise.

So you can treat it as any `TextView`with it's properties as:

```
emptyTextView.setTextColor(...);
emptyTextView.setTextSize(...);
```